# Is it possible to boot ubuntu physical partition on winds 10 host on a virtual box?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning

I use regularly Ubuntu but sometimes i feel the need to use Windows 10 accessibility on running programs that are compatible with Windows, but also need to use Ubuntu full performance at the same time, so i have dual-booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, but it would be more useful for me if somehow i could use Ubuntu dual-booted partition on a virtual box on the Windows 10 host.

Disk2vhd Prt Src

[image: Disk2vhd Prt Src]

But I have tried the Disk2vhd program on Winds 10 to open a Windows 10 physical drive, but i can 't find the Ubuntu partition on the program to open it, also heard the term "virtualization" but I couldn't get anything :/.

Thanks in advance if someone could help me with this problem. :)

Comment: You can look at this answer for how to set up RAW disk access https://superuser.com/questions/1054838/virtualbox-windows-host-ubuntu-guest-installed-on-raw-partition?rq=1

Comment: If you just need access to ubuntu files, use Ext2fsd https://www.ext2fsd.com/